# IntelliJ IDEA 2019 no longer terminates previous process on run

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I have a Kotlin/JVM Gradle project that I'm working on in IntelliJ IDEA CE.

I unchecked *Allow parallel run* on my "Application" Run Configuration, so that IDEA would only allow a single instance of my process. I got used to the behaviour where after I press Run, the previous process is terminated before the new process is launched.

Today, I upgraded from 2018.3 (maybe?) to 2019.1.1 (details below[0]), and even though that checkbox is unchecked, every time I press run it launches a new process. The new process always quits immediately because it binds to the same port as the first process, which is still running. I need to quit the old process(es) manually.

My project is unmodified; the only thing I did was upgrade IntelliJ using the upgrade prompt when I launched it today.

[image: Screenshot of my run configuration]

When I hit run, I want the old process to quit first so it doesn't conflict with the new one. How do I get this behaviour back?

[0]:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.1 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-191.6707.61, built on April 16, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b44 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.14.3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1 delegates build and run actions to Gradle by default. With the delegation enabled, some options from the run configurations [have no effect](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-189944).

The solution is to disable the build/run delegation in File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | Runner:

[image: delegate]

Answer (score 1):

In IntelliJ 2020 the gradle settings look like this, set all to IntelliJ IDEA:

[image]